# When to use the sandbox?

Tags: discussion

Using the sandbox is unnecessary in many circumstances (think [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/39752/sing-happy-birthday-to-your-favourite-programming-language)), especially if you are a good question writer.

However, it is not always obvious (at least to me) if a question needs to go through the sandbox process.

For example, I considered
[Prime Quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/39872/hole-2-prime-quine) to be a straightforward question, although it was recommended for the sandbox.

My question is, What qualities are "problem points", that is, what qualities require **extra** clarification?

An example based on Prime Quine would be:

```
Define what built in functions can be used thoroughly, 
especially for well known mathematical structs, like prime numbers.
```

I am hoping this resource will help people create better questions, as well as help with the sandbox process.

Answer (score 5):

Some questions need to go through the sandbox and have improvements made before they are ready to post, other questions are perfect already. The way to find out which one of these applies to your question is to post it in the sandbox. Questions that have only positive feedback and upvotes can then be posted in main.

The reason for having a sandbox is that most questions *seem* ready until they have had a few additional eyes look at them, and then little improvements are highlighted.

It is better to have a number of human minds review each new question, rather than try to settle on a heuristic for determining which questions need reviewing.

Answer (score 1):

For comparison, here's a question I asked that never went through the sandbox, and (I beleve) did not need to go through the sandbox:

[Find the Smoothest Number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/36384/find-the-smoothest-number)

Important characteristics:

1. Nothing fancy is going on at all. Just a standard code-golf, no content restrictions or anything.
2. I am a rather experienced user. I have seen may good questions.

I think that a question like this might be considered safe to skip sandbox, but anything else probably should go through the sandbox.